# Zend Framework Get Last Part of URL

Tags: php, zend-framework

I need to get the last part of the URL while using Zend Framework from a View (.phtml)

So my URL currently is something like: site.com/some/other/path

I need to return "path" -- how can I do this from a view?

Answer (score 4):

Use `strrpos()` to find the position of the last '/' in the string, and return everything after it:

```
$url = 'site.com/some/other/path';    
echo substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' ) + 1 ); // Output: 'path'
```

To get the URL, you can use:

```
basename($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
```

as [stated by John Cartwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112522/zend-framework-get-last-part-of-url/7112581#answer-7112618).

Answer (score 1):

Either assign a view variable from the controller:

```
$path = $this->_request->getRequestUri();
$parts = explode('/', $path);
$lastPathComponent = end($parts);

$this->view->lastPathComponent = $lastPathComponent;
```

Or, if you are going to use this in a view that's used for multiple controllers (e.g. a layout), create a view helper that returns the last path component, and call it from the view:

```
<?=$this->escape($this->lastPathComponent())?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the url from the request object, then apply basename() to the result.

```
echo basename($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri());
```