# Get the Value of the URL in ZF

Tags: php, zend-framework, action

I want to get the this following value from the URL in zend.

```
$FrontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$Router = $FrontController->getRouter();
$Router->addRoute("homestore",
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route (
    "index/store",
    array("controller" => "index", "action" => "home")
);
```

I want to get the `store`  from the URL instead of actual action value that is `home`. How could I do this. I have tried a lot of searches but can't find any thing useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current route name by doing this:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getCurrentRouteName();
```

Or what you can do is just get the full request URI, and get the value from there:

```
// This is inside a Controller.
$this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Comment: @Najam-us-Saqib The `$this->url()` is simply an action helper and proxies to the router.

Answer (score 2):

If you have htaccess enable than use this **`basename($this->getRequest()->getRequestUri())`** source https://stackoverflow.com/a/7112581